# Making a canvas able to stay on top of another canvas- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm a beginner and currently developing a little mario-like game. I have this player which runs and jumps around and it should be able to jump up on these paddles. Something in my code is wrong though and it just doesn't work. What I want to happen is that the player's y velocity should be 0 and therefore stop when it is on top of the paddle.

```
var player = {
    side: 40,
    x: 0,
    y: canvas.height - 40,
    velY: 0,
    velX: 0,
    speed: 4,
    jumping: false,
    grav: 0.17,
    alive: true
  }

var paddle = {
  height: 20,
  width: 100,
  x: 250,
  y: canvas.height - 30,
}

  if((player.y - player.side <= paddle.y) && (player.y - player.side >= paddle.y + paddle.width) && (player.x - player.side > paddle.x ) && (player.x - player.side < paddle.x + paddle.width)){
    player.y  = paddle.y - player.side;
    player.velY = 0;
  }
```

Here is a fiddle where you can see for yourself what happens. https://jsfiddle.net/Scrubben/4d53tbLd/  (You move with arrow keys).

If you want me to add more code let me know. Thanks!
Also, please don't use any JQuery.

Comment: You forgot to post the fiddle

Comment: Opps, I added it now.